# Can IObservable.Catch continue with the same observable

Tags: system.reactive

Suppose a have an `IObservable`:

```
IObservable<long> obs = ...;
```

Can I do the following to guarantee that the observable will never ever stop?

```
IObservable<long> resilientObs = obs.Catch(obs);
```

So when an exception is caught, continue with the same sequence that generated the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this with a Cold observable (i.e. an Observable that returns a new sequence every time)

```
obs.Retry();
```

But even then, you're not "resuming" an Observable, you're just restarting it.

If you wanted to maintain a persistent connection (say, a web socket that gets terminated because of an error), you need a factory function + Defer:

```
Observable.Defer(() => createNewObservable())
    .Retry();
```

To give you better advice, you need to tell us the nature of what obs is and what you're trying to do.

Comment: The use case is exactly what you describe: a socket that generates a stream of data that can be terminated. Thanks for the answer.